# Sort the data by column

Tags: excel, vba, columnsorting

Earlier the code was running well but now I am again facing problem in sort field. Error (run time error 424-object required with Sort value being nothing
)

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim LR As Long
Dim SR As Range

LR = Range("D1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set SR = Range("A1:AM" & LR)

With Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange.SR
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Should `sortRange = WorksheetFunction.Concat("A1:", "AM", LR)` be `sortRange = WorksheetFunction.Concat("A1", "AM" & LR)`

Comment: I tried fixing with & but still getting error (run time error 450 -wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment ) at .SetRange.SR

Comment: Oh! You don't need that `.`. Use `.SetRange SR` (This assumes that `SR` is a valid range. I think you should actually do `Set SR = Range("A1:AM" & LR)`. Otherwise I *think* your `sortRange` will be a string of the values in those cells, not a valid "string range"?

Comment: Hi Bruce, with setting SR as you mentioned still getting same type of error and SR being no value

Comment: What is `LR`? After you do `LR = ...`, add `Debug.Print LR`, is it showing as 0?  (To see the debug print, in the VBEditor press `CTRL+G` to see the Immediate Window.)  I suspect it may be better to do `LR = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: the value is 783187 which is last row number in worksheet data that I have.

Comment: Also, remove that `SR.Select` line ...you don't need it. Don't think that'll solve the issue, but just wanted to note.

Comment: With your code as written, and `SR.Select` deleted, that error line should read `.SetRange SR`. It works here. If that doesn't work, what does `?SR.Address` return in the immediate window.

Comment: Thanks@BruceWayne and @Ron. It is working now.

Comment: @BruceWayne. The code was running well, I am getting error on sort value. Can you please help.

Comment: What line is throwing an error?

Comment: @BruceWayne  I am again facing problem in sort field. Error (run time error 424-object required with Sort value being nothing )